# How to align items in VS 2010 UML class diagram designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I want to align my classes on the VS 2010 architect UML class diagram tool. I can't seem to find the toolbar or menus to allow alignments of elements on the design surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an add-in to to this. See [Align Shapes on a UML diagram](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/UML-command-to-Align-4139c0d7).

See also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vsarch/thread/53c09ac3-7a60-47e9-aef1-c81c3674181c

Comment: Thanks! The example you provided in the link is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's support for that. Feel free to submit feedback for this at http://connect.microsoft.com.